# Lena gone in scipy

Tags: python, image, image-processing, scipy

I just noticed that lena has been removed from the latest version scipy. I have been using this image for quite a bit during my PhD, to measure image performance and I can't really change it at this stage (it would mean remeasuring everything and that is not really an option.). Are you aware of a package that will re-enable lena? I would prefer that to having to copy the file every time. It would probably be quite easy to make, but it would be handy if someone already had it.

Edit: I made the package, you can find it here: https://github.com/dboonz/reshow_lena

Comment: Did you try searching google for the image? https://www.google.com/search?q=lena&biw=1270&bih=1466&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj33sqM89fPAhVEOSYKHV7vDXMQ_AUIBigB

Comment: " It would probably be quite easy to make" well, shes quite old now, I don't think the photo would look the same, unfortunately.  However, can't you just use the previous version of scypy? No one stops you from that

Comment: Luckily, SciPy is hosted on GitHub, where you can access old versions. https://github.com/scipy/scipy/tree/maintenance/0.16.x/scipy/misc . This was [embarrassingly easy to find](https://www.google.com/search?q=scipy+lena+photo).

Answer (score 5):

A quick trip to Google indicates that the file `lena.dat` can be found, for example, at https://github.com/minrk/scipy-1/blob/master/scipy/misc/lena.dat

Put this file in the same directory as a module with the following code:

```
def lena():
    import pickle, os
    fname = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'lena.dat')
    f = open(fname,'rb')
    lena = array(pickle.load(f))
    f.close()
    return lena
```

I copied this code directly from the Python 2.7 version of `scipy/misc/common.py`.

Now you can do

```
from mymodule import lena
```

If you don't want to change your imports at all, you have to include `lena.dat` in the folder `lib/site-packages/scipy/misc`, and add the function to `commmon.py`; you also need to make sure that `lena` is exported in `__all__`, and that `__init__.py` imports `*` from `common.py`.

Comment: lena.dat from the link https://github.com/minrk/scipy-1/blob/master/scipy/misc/lena.dat, will not be worked with python3

Comment: You need to generate it on your own using python3
```
from matplotlib.image import imread
import pickle
img = imread('lena_gray.gif')
print(type(img))
img[:,:,0].dump("lena.dat")
```